# Need help creating a loop

Tags: c++

My loop needs to be able to generate the letters A B C ext. verticaly like this:

```
A
B
C
```

Yet when it reaches letter J it needs to start over. The user inputs how many lines to generate through the command line. I'm having trouble figuring out a way to make the loop start over after it reaches the letter J.  I have my code here:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int letter = 65;

    for(int i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]); i++)
    {
        cout <<(char)letter++;
        cout << endl;

        if(letter == 75)
        {
            int letter = 65;
        }
    }   

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: @taliezin was 20s faster :)

Comment: have a counter, reset it when you get to j ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the `int letter` is replaced with `letter` inside the `if` statement

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int letter = 65;

    for(int i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]); i++)
    {
        cout <<(char)letter++;
        cout << endl;

        if(letter == 75)
        {
            letter = 65;
        }
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Output with input as 16:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  using namespace std;

  assert(argc >= 1 + 1); //Fail with an error message rather than a segfault if the argument isn't provided

  int n_iterations = atoi(argv[1]);
  int range_size = 'J' - 'A' + 1; //include 'J'

  for(int i=0; i < n_iterations; i++){
    cout<< char('A'+i % range_size) << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The main points are:

- call `atoi` once rather than in each iteration
- descriptive code (i.e., `'A'`) is better than magic numbers
- to wrap around a number, use `i % range_size` rather than `if`
- not flushing after each line (`endl` flushes) will be better for performance in pipelines (if you want performance you'll also likely want to turn of syncing with `stdio` by doing `ios::sync_with_stdio(false);`)

---

If you really want to use `if`, then the problem of:

```
 if(letter == 75)
        {
            int letter = 65;
        }
```

is that since `int letter = 65;` is in a new scope (=pair of curly braces), it will create a new local `letter` variable that will overshadow the original `letter`.

```
if(letter == 75){
   letter = 65;
}
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: Not only is `'A'` more descriptive than the magic number, it is portable to odd character sets that don't match Unicode or ASCII for the letters. +1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here :

```
 if(letter == 75)
 {  
  int letter = 65;
 }
```

You are redeclaring `letter` inside the braces, instead of modifying your existing `letter` variable. This `letter` variable is local to that block, and hides your other `letter` variable.

You could have debugged this yourself by putting a breakpoint at the start of your program, and watching the letter variable there. You would have noticed it is not modified when going into the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   if(letter == 75)
      {
        letter = 65;
       }
```

Comment: And get an infinite loop if the argument is more than 10 ?

Comment: @Neuron the continue is useless, there is nothing to skip after the if.

Comment: @Leiaz: agreed, my bad

Comment: @YuraVasylenko: Agreed

Comment: Edited my answer also

Comment: @Leiaz The question was about the way to start it over. I guess  it is not hard to add one more check within if condition to check for exit criteria.

Comment: @Leiaz ,I understood this task wrong. You are right

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do the task. For example you could write the program the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    const int N = 'J' - 'A' + 1;

    int n = 0;

    if ( argv[1] ) n = std::atoi( argv[1] ); 

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) std::cout << char( 'A' + i % N ) << std::endl;
}
```

For example if the command line argument will be set to 14 then the output will look like

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
A
B
C
D
```

Or you can write the main loop as it is shown in this demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    const char A = 'A', J = 'J';

    int n = 0;

    if ( argv[1] ) n = std::atoi( argv[1] ); 

    for ( char c = A; n-- > 0; c == J ? c = A : ++c ) std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

The output will look the same way as above.

One more approach.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    const char *letters = "ABCDEFGHIJ";

    int n = 0;

    if ( argv[1] ) n = std::atoi( argv[1] ); 

    for ( const char *p = letters; n-- > 0; *++p ? p : p = letters )
    {        
        std::cout << *p << std::endl;           
    }        
}
```

As for your code then you should not use magic numbers like 65 or 75. First of all it makes difficult to understand the code and in other coding systems as for example EBCDIC these magic numbers will not make sense.

Also in this code snippet

```
if(letter == 75)
{
    int letter = 65;
}
```

you are declaring one more local variable with name `letter` that will not be alive after the closing brace. So this code snippet also does not make sense.